# How do I customize the content and location of a tooltip using Syncfusion in Xamarin?

Tags: xaml, user-interface, xamarin, tooltip, syncfusion

I'm setting up a stacking column chart in XAML using Syncfusion for Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017. I've tried adding custom text according to the example [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfchart/tooltip?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=xaml), but I run into an exception when the tooltip is activated. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<chart:SfChart.Series>

<chart:StackingColumnSeries EnableTooltip="True"
  Width="0.5"
  ItemsSource="{Binding TankLevels}" 
  XBindingPath="Name" YBindingPath="Level1">
        <chart:StackingColumnSeries.TooltipTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="test"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </chart:StackingColumnSeries.TooltipTemplate>

  <chart:BarSeries.ColorModel>
    <chart:ChartColorModel Palette="Custom" CustomBrushes="{Binding WaterColor}">         
    </chart:ChartColorModel>
  </chart:BarSeries.ColorModel>

</chart:StackingColumnSeries>
```

Comment: Can you provide more details?Such as error message.I did tha same thing as you ,and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have analyzed your code snippet and prepared a sample based on it, and the sample can be downloaded from the link below.

Sample: [215585](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/215585/ze/215585204882982)

I am afraid I was not able to reproduce the reported issue, it is working fine. Can you please provide more information like a stack trace on the exception?

Thanks,
Michael

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was using an outdated version of Syncfusion's Xamarin Controls. I didn't have any more issues after updating to the newest version.